# How to Add exe file as prerequisites into .net setup

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, setup-project

I am developing a WPF application in .NET and I create the setup for that project. My project needs additional software like Adobe Flash and Adobe Reader. I am trying to add both Setups  to my project setup. my need is when the user runs my set up it will automatically install both softwares on the client system. How can I do that? Is it possible to add that setups in prerequisites? If it's possible, can you kindly tell how can I achieve my needs.

Comment: What kind of setup software are you using?

Comment: @nvoigt i am using .msi installer

Comment: What software do you use to create the MSI installer?

Comment: @nvoigt visual studio 2010

Comment: No sorry, I haven't used those setup projects for years. VS2010 is outdated and the setup projects were not continued into 2012 and 2013. If you want to use newer version of Visual Studio in the future, you may want to use a setup software that will work on those versions, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way it works is - the setup.exe installs prerequisites and then your MSI installs your project. There are many reasons for this. Is there an actual problem or do you just believe your MSI file should be able to install prerequisites like the .NET framework, SQL Express and so on?

If you have some problem in adding them at some of the stages, you can check this article - [Add prerequisites to .Net project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35976/Add-Prerequisites-of-NET-Framework-in-Visual-Studi)

To add exe files in the setup you can try with creating a Bootstrapper packages. There is a good article in MSDN - [Bootstrapper Package](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165429.aspx).  Basically you just have to create a product manifest and a package manifest, copy them along with your distributable file to : \Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages. Visual studio will automatically pick it up.

Comment: yes i can add .net frameworks in prerequisites but how can i add adobe reader and flash ??????

Comment: See my update in the answer.

Comment: thanks a lot it helps me to solve my problem